# Set flag to golang request

Tags: http, go, curl, request

I have a CURL string `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json`
It has a flag `--unix-sock`
How can i set this flag to http request in golang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [DialContext field of http.Transport](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.DialContext) to connect to unix sockets (most error handling omitted for brevity):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func main() {
    c := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
                return (&net.Dialer{}).DialContext(ctx, "unix", "/var/run/docker.sock")
            },
        },
    }

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost/containers/json", nil)

    res, err := c.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    b, _ := httputil.DumpResponse(res, true)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```